# Android Separator with Padding

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following separator :

```
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp" />
```

However padding does not do anything. The separator is touching the sides, and it looks kinda bad. How can I make it have an equal padding from left and right?

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with a margin instead.-

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />
```

By the way, consider keeping your dimension values in a `dimens.xml` resources file to avoid hardcoding.